# WP8.1 Combobox opens under other controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, combobox

I have a following problem,
my combobox on winphone8.1 opens its items under others controls.. can anybody have any solve solutions?

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Combobox Grid.Row="0"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your control to cover other items, instead of pushing them, just give your control a RowSpan. It makes the control span over multiple rows.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="2"/>
  <Combobox Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Notice that the Combobox is declared after the TextBoxes, in order to be in front of them and cover them.

On a sidenote, there's no need to explicitly set Grid.Row (or column) if it's 0 since that's its default value. So you could just ommit Grid.Row="0" on your Combobox. The same goes when setting * as height or width of a row/column defition. Can be shortened to

```
<RowDefinition/>
```

Comment: so what when I want to have static height of row and i want to expanded combobox covers others rows?

Comment: considering playing with MinHeight and MaxHeight as required

Comment: I want to cover other controls like showing expanded combobox on the top layer of content and dont move other rows. ( grid height auto doesn't work.. :( )

yes i know but I using grid.row=0 because its more readable and easier to change if want

Comment: In that case you should use RowSpan - edited my answer